# Captcha not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor, entity-framework-4.1

I am implementing captcha in one of my register form

In Example.Cs file I wrote the below :

```
public static class CaptchaHelper
 {
  public static string Captcha(this HtmlHelper helper, string text)
       {
           string srcPath = System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Handler1.ashx");
           string htmlContent = string.Empty;
           htmlContent += "<script type=\"text/javascript\">function __rc(){document.getElementById(\"" + text +
                          "\").src = \"../Handler1.ashx?query=\" + Math.random();}</script>";
           htmlContent += string.Format("<img id=\"{0}\" src=\"{1}\" alt=\"Captcha Image\"/>", text, srcPath);
           htmlContent += "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"javascript:__rc();\">Reset</a>";
           return htmlContent;
       }
   }
```

And in View (.cshtml) I wrote the below :

```
      @Html.Captcha("Sample")
```

In place of image its showing the script can any one help on this.

Thanks
Bhanu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one...

```
public static class CaptchaHelper
 {
  public static MvcHtmlString Captcha(this HtmlHelper helper, string text)
       {
           string srcPath = System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Handler1.ashx");
           string htmlContent = string.Empty;
           htmlContent += "<script type=\"text/javascript\">function __rc(){document.getElementById(\"" + text +
                          "\").src = \"../Handler1.ashx?query=\" + Math.random();}</script>";
           htmlContent += string.Format("<img id=\"{0}\" src=\"{1}\" alt=\"Captcha Image\"/>", text, srcPath);
           htmlContent += "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"javascript:__rc();\">Reset</a>";
           return MvcHtmlString.Create(htmlContent.ToString());
       }
   }
```

Edit... Try this line...

```
htmlContent += string.Format("<img id=" + text + " src=" + srcPath + " alt=\"Captcha Image\"/>", text, srcPath);
```

Comment: getting only the heading and Reset link can you please help on this

Comment: getting the same - displaying Captcha heading and Image ResetLink